# Common scroll top function for all menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to write common function for all scroll function.Now It is working with separate function for all 'li'.If I write the script directly in on click event it is working.But It is not working if I try to call the function.

```js
function myFunction(a) {
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('a').offset().top-40}, 1000);
}
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navMenu">
     <!-- <li class="test1" onclick="$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#consulting').offset().top-40}, 1000);" ><a href="#consulting">Consulting & Solutions</a></li> -->
     <li class="test1" onclick="myFunction(#consulting)" ><a href="#consulting">Consulting & Solutions</a></li> 
     <li class="test2" onclick="$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#segments').offset().top-40}, 1000);" ><a href="#segments">Segments</a></li>
    
   </ul>

<div id="consulting">
  1st div
</div>
<div id="segments">
  2nd div
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function myFunction(a) {

   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('a').offset().top-40}, 1000);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navMenu">
              <!-- <li class="test1" onclick="$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#consulting').offset().top-40}, 1000);" ><a href="#consulting">Consulting & Solutions</a></li> -->
              <li class="test1" onclick="myFunction(#consulting)" ><a href="#consulting">Consulting & Solutions</a></li> 
              <li class="test2" onclick="myFunction(#segments)" ><a href="#segments">Segments</a></li>

            </ul>

<div id="consulting">
  1st div
</div>
<div id="segments">
  2nd div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  function myFunction(a) {

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('a').offset().top-40}, 1000);
  }
});
```

Try this